# Paging combobox in ExtJS 4.1

Tags: combobox, paging, extjs4.1

can anyone give me an example about Paging combobox in ExtJS4.1.

i understand the paging combobox, but i can't reproduce in extjs4.1.

[Ufficial sencha forum old post about it.](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?6604-ComboBox-Paging-Need-Help-Understanding...) 
thank for any type of help.

Answer (score 1):

Go to http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/example/form/forum-search.html and type in extjs into the form field, you'll see it.

The source is here :
http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/extjs-build/examples/form/forum-search.js